# Is there a limit on functions in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function

As to answer a question on Super User, I was making a sample spreadsheet on Google Docs. I made it first in Excel 2010 on my computer to copy/paste it later on. When I tried to copy a formula that contained the "MATCH" formula, it didn't work (it works in Excel though).

Is Google Spreadsheets limited in formulas or does it work with its own set of formulas and can't I compare it to the Office Excel one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Docs has size limits.](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37603) [There can be 2 million cells containing formulas.](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2505921)

You can compare the Excel functions with this [Google Spreadsheet function list.](https://support.google.com/docs/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs) While there are some common functions, Google Spreadsheet does have its own set of formulas

*Google spreadsheets also have complexity limits. Every time a cell is updated, any cell that references it will also be recalculated. If formulas become too complex or take too long to calculate, the spreadsheet will timeout during calculation.*

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a list comparing the functions between the two](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Avw3I-JOj4d1dEc1djhMeGdGc0JySTVnNVRBNzJ0VVE&output=html):

```
+----------------+---------------+
| Excel          | Google        |
+----------------+---------------+
| ABS            | ABS           |
| ACCRINT        | ACCRINT       |
| ACCRINTM       | ACCRINTM      |
| ACOS           | ACOS          |
| ACOSH          | ACOSH         |
| ADD            |               |
| ADDRESS        | ADDRESS       |
| AMORDEGRC      |               |
| AMORLINC       |               |
| AND            | AND           |
| AREAS          |               |
| ASC            |               |
| ASIN           | ASIN          |
| ASINH          | ASINH         |
| ATAN           | ATAN          |
| ATAN2          | ATAN2         |
| ATANH          | ATANH         |
| AVEDEV         | AVEDEV        |
| AVERAGE        | AVERAGE       |
| AVERAGEA       | AVERAGEA      |
| BAHTTEXT       |               |
| BESSELI        |               |
| BESSELJ        |               |
| BESSELK        |               |
| BESSELY        |               |
| BETADIST       |               |
| BETAINV        |               |
| BIN2DEC        | BIN2DEC       |
| BIN2HEX        | BIN2HEX       |
| BIN2OCT        | BIN2OCT       |
| BINOMDIST      | BINOMDIST     |
| CEILING        | CEILING       |
| CELL           |               |
| CHAR           | CHAR          |
| CHIDIST        |               |
| CHIINV         |               |
| CHITEST        |               |
| CHOOSE         | CHOOSE        |
| CLEAN          |               |
| CODE           | CODE          |
| COLUMN         | COLUMN        |
| COLUMNS        | COLUMNS       |
| COMBIN         | COMBIN        |
| COMPLEX        |               |
| CONCAT         |               |
| CONCATENATE    | CONCATENATE   |
| CONFIDENCE     | CONFIDENCE    |
| CONVERT        |               |
| CORREL         | CORREL        |
| COS            | COS           |
| COSH           | COSH          |
| COUNT          | COUNT         |
| COUNTA         | COUNTA        |
| COUNTBLANK     | COUNTBLANK    |
| COUNTIF        | COUNTIF       |
| COUPDAYBS      | COUPDAYBS     |
| COUPDAYS       | COUPDAYS      |
| COUPDAYSNC     | COUPDAYSNC    |
| COUPNCD        | COUPNCD       |
| COUPNUM        | COUPNUM       |
| COUPPCD        | COUPPCD       |
| COVAR          | COVAR         |
| CRITBINOM      | CRITBINOM     |
| CUMIPMT        | CUMIPMT       |
| CUMPRINC       | CUMPRINC      |
| DATE           | DATE          |
| DATEDIF        |               |
| DateString     |               |
| DATEVALUE      | DATEVALUE     |
| DAVERAGE       |               |
| DAY            | DAY           |
| DAYS360        | DAYS360       |
| DB             | DB            |
| DBCS           |               |
| DCOUNT         |               |
| DCOUNTA        |               |
| DDB            | DDB           |
| DEC2BIN        | DEC2BIN       |
| DEC2HEX        | DEC2HEX       |
| DEC2OCT        | DEC2OCT       |
| DEGREES        | DEGREES       |
| DELTA          |               |
| DEVSQ          | DEVSQ         |
| DGET           |               |
| DISC           | DISC          |
| DIVIDE         |               |
| DMAX           |               |
| DMIN           |               |
| DOLLAR         | DOLLAR        |
| DOLLARDE       | DOLLARDE      |
| DOLLARFR       | DOLLARFR      |
| DPRODUCT       |               |
| DSTDEV         |               |
| DSTDEVP        |               |
| DSUM           |               |
| DURATION       | DURATION      |
| DVAR           |               |
| DVARP          |               |
| EDATE          | EDATE         |
| EFFECT         | EFFECT        |
| EOMONTH        | EOMONTH       |
| EQ             |               |
| ERF            |               |
| ERFC           |               |
| ERROR.TYPE     | ERROR.TYPE    |
| EUROCONVERT    |               |
| EVEN           | EVEN          |
| EXACT          | EXACT         |
| EXP            | EXP           |
| EXPONDIST      | EXPONDIST     |
| FACT           | FACT          |
| FACTDOUBLE     | FACTDOUBLE    |
| FALSE          | FALSE         |
| FILTER         |               |
| FDIST          |               |
| FIND           | FIND          |
| FindB          |               |
| FINV           |               |
| FISHER         | FISHER        |
| FISHERINV      | FISHERINV     |
| FIXED          | FIXED         |
| FLOOR          | FLOOR         |
| FORECAST       | FORECAST      |
| FREQUENCY      | FREQUENCY     |
| Ftest          |               |
| FV             | FV            |
| FVSCHEDULE     | FVSCHEDULE    |
| GAMMADIST      |               |
| GAMMAINV       |               |
| GAMMALN        |               |
| GCD            | GCD           |
| GEOMEAN        | GEOMEAN       |
| GoogleFinance  |               |
| GoogleLookup   |               |
| GESTEP         |               |
| GETPIVOTDATA * |               |
| GROWTH         | GROWTH        |
| GT             |               |
| GTE            |               |
| HARMEAN        | HARMEAN       |
| HEX2BIN        | HEX2BIN       |
| HEX2DEC        | HEX2DEC       |
| HEX2OCT        | HEX2OCT       |
| HLOOKUP        | HLOOKUP       |
| HOUR           | HOUR          |
| HYPERLINK      | HYPERLINK     |
| HYPGEOMDIST    | HYPGEOMDIST   |
| IF             | IF            |
| IFERROR        |               |
| ImportData     |               |
| ImportFeed     |               |
| ImportHtml     |               |
| ImportRange    |               |
| ImportXML      |               |
| IMABS          | **            |
| IMAGINARY      | **            |
| IMARGUMENT     | **            |
| IMCONJUGATE    | **            |
| IMCOS          | **            |
| IMDIV          | **            |
| IMEXP          | **            |
| IMLN           | **            |
| IMLOG10        | **            |
| IMLOG2         | **            |
| IMPOWER        | **            |
| IMPRODUCT      | **            |
| IMREAL         | **            |
| IMSIN          | **            |
| IMSQRT         | **            |
| IMSUB          | **            |
| IMSUM          | **            |
| INDEX          | INDEX         |
| INDIRECT       | INDIRECT      |
| INFO           |               |
| INT            | INT           |
| INTERCEPT      | INTERCEPT     |
| INTRATE        | INTRATE       |
| IPMT           | IPMT          |
| IRR            | IRR           |
| ISBLANK        | ISBLANK       |
| ISERR          | ISERR         |
| ISERROR        | ISERROR       |
| ISEVEN         | ISEVEN        |
| ISLOGICAL      | ISLOGICAL     |
| ISNA           | ISNA          |
| ISNONTEXT      | ISNONTEXT     |
| ISNUMBER       | ISNUMBER      |
| ISODD          | ISODD         |
| ISPMT          |               |
| ISREF          | ISREF         |
| ISTEXT         | ISTEXT        |
| JIS            |               |
| * KURT         | KURT          |
| LARGE          | LARGE         |
| LCM            | LCM           |
| LEFT           | LEFT          |
| LeftB          |               |
| LEN            | LEN           |
| LenB           |               |
| LINEST         | LINEST        |
| LN             | LN            |
| LOG            | LOG           |
| LOG10          | LOG10         |
| LOGEST         | LOGEST        |
| LOGINV         | LOGINV        |
| LOGNORMDIST    | LOGNORMDIST   |
| LOOKUP         | LOWER         |
| LT             |               |
| LTE            |               |
| LOWER          |               |
| MATCH          | MATCH         |
| MAX            | MAX           |
| MAXA           | MAXA          |
| MDETERM        | MDETERM       |
| MDURATION      | MDURATION     |
| MEDIAN         | MEDIAN        |
| MID            | MID           |
| MidB           |               |
| MIN            | MIN           |
| MINE *         | MINA          |
| MINUS          |               |
| MINUTE         | MINUTE        |
| MINVERSE       | MINVERSE      |
| MIRR           | MIRR          |
| MMULT          | MMULT         |
| MOD            | MOD           |
| MODE           | MODE          |
| MONTH          | MONTH         |
| MROUND         | MROUND        |
| MULTINOMIAL    | MULTINOMIAL   |
| MULTIPLY       |               |
| N              | N             |
| IN             | IN            |
| NE             |               |
| NEGBINOMDIST   | NEGBINOMDIST  |
| NETWORKDAYS    | NETWORKDAYS   |
| NOMINAL        | NOMINAL       |
| NORMDIST       | NORMDIST      |
| NORMINV        | NORMINV       |
| NORMSDIST      | NORMSDIST     |
| NORMSINV       | NORMSINV      |
| NOT            | NOT           |
| NOW            | NOW           |
| NPER           | NPER          |
| NPV            | NPV           |
| NUMBERSTRING   |               |
| OCT2BIN        | OCT2BIN       |
| OCT2DEC        | OCT2DEC       |
| OCT2HEX        | OCT2HEX       |
| ODD            | ODD           |
| ODDFPRICE      |               |
| ODDFYIELD      |               |
| ODDLPRICE      |               |
| ODDLYIELD      |               |
| OFFSET         | OFFSET        |
| OR             | OR            |
| PEARSON        | PEARSON       |
| PERCENTILE     | PERCENTILE    |
| PERCENTRANK    | PERCENTRANK   |
| PERMUT         | PERMUT        |
| * Phonetic     |               |
| PI             | PI            |
| PMT            | PMT           |
| POISSON        | POISSON       |
| POWER          | POW           |
| POWER          |               |
| PPMT           | PPMT          |
| PRICE          | PRICE         |
| PRICEDISC      | PRICEDISC     |
| PRICEMAT       | PRICEMAT      |
| PROB           | PROB          |
| PRODUCT        | PRODUCT       |
| PROPER         | PROPER        |
| PV             | PV            |
| QUARTILE       | QUARTILE      |
| QUOTIENT       | QUOTIENT      |
| RADIANS        | RADIANS       |
| RAND           | RAND          |
| RANDBETWEEN    | RANDBETWEEN   |
| RANK           | RANK          |
| RATE           | RATE          |
| RECEIVED       | RECEIVED      |
| REPLACE        | REPLACE       |
| REPLACEB       |               |
| REPT           | REPT          |
| RIGHT          | RIGHT         |
| RightB         |               |
| ROMAN          |               |
| ROUND          | ROUND         |
| ROUNDDOWN      | ROUNDDOWN     |
| ROUNDUP        | ROUNDUP       |
| ROW            | ROW           |
| ROWS           | ROWS          |
| RSQ            | RSQ           |
| RTD            |               |
| SEARCH         | SEARCH        |
| SEARCHB        |               |
| SECOND         | SECOND        |
| SERIESSUM      | SERIESSUM     |
| SIGN           | SIGN          |
| SIN            | SIN           |
| SINH           | SINH          |
| SKEW           | SKEW          |
| SLN            | SLN           |
| SLOPE          | SLOPE         |
| SMALL          | SMALL         |
| SORT           |               |
| SPLIT          |               |
| SQRT           | SQRT          |
| SQRTPI         | SQRTPI        |
| STANDARDIZE    | STANDARDIZE   |
| STDEV          | STDEV         |
| STDEVA         | STDEVA        |
| STDEVP         | STDEVP        |
| STDEVPA        | STDEVPA       |
| STEYX          | STEYX         |
| SUBSTITUTE     | SUBSTITUTE    |
| SUBTOTAL       |               |
| SUM            | SUM           |
| SUMIF          | SUMIF         |
| SUMPRODUCT     | SUMPRODUCT    |
| SUMSQ          | SUMSQ         |
| SUMX2MY2       | SUMX2MY2      |
| SUMX2PY2       | SUMX2PY2      |
| SUMXMY2        | SUMXMY2       |
| SYD            | SYD           |
| T              | T             |
| TAN            | TAN           |
| TANH           | TANH          |
| TBILLEQ        | TBILLEQ       |
| TBILLPRICE     | TBILLPRICE    |
| TBILLYIELD     | TBILLYIELD    |
| TDIST          | TEXT          |
| TEXT           |               |
| TIME           | TIME          |
| TIMEVALUE      |               |
| TINV           |               |
| TODAY          | TODAY         |
| TRANSPOSE      | TRANSPOSE     |
| TREND          | TREND         |
| TRIM           | TRIM          |
| TRIMMEAN       | TRIMMEAN      |
| TRUE           | TRUE          |
| TRUNC          | TRUNC         |
| UNIQUE         |               |
| TTEST          |               |
| TYPE           |               |
| UPPER          | UPPER         |
| USDOLLAR       |               |
| VALUE          | VALUE         |
| VAR            | VAR           |
| STICK          | STICK         |
| VARP           | VARP          |
| VARPA          | VARPA         |
| VDB            |               |
| VLOOKUP        | VLOOKUP       |
| WEEKDAY        | WEEKDAY       |
| WEEKNUM        |               |
| WEIBULL        | WEIBULL       |
| WORKDAY        | WORKDAY       |
| XIRR           | XIRR          |
| XNPV           | XNPV          |
| YEAR           | YEAR          |
| YEARFRAC       | YEARFRAC      |
| YIELD          | YIELD         |
| YIELDDISC      | YIELDDISC     |
| YIELDMAT       |               |
| ZTEST          | ZTEST         |
+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Also, may be out of date. Google is adding new functions quite often, without much ado, not even a release note.  For example, the ROMAN function not exists in both.